# Shortcode Attribute not defined

Tags: shortcode, errors

I have a shortcode `[gf_popup pause="1000"  location="bottom"]` and the location attribute keeps coming back as `Uncaught ReferenceError: bottom is not defined`.  Any thoughts on why?  Here is the main part of the code:

```
function gfpu_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tags = '')
{

    // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
$atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

// override default attributes with user attributes
$gfpu_atts = shortcode_atts([
                                 'pause'    => 5000,
                                 'location' => 'false',
                                 'popTrigger'   => 'false',
                             ], $atts, $tag);

    $timer = esc_html__($gfpu_atts['pause'], 'gf_popup');
    $location = esc_html__($gfpu_atts['location'], 'gf_popup');
    $popTrigger = esc_html__($gfpu_atts['popTrigger'], 'gf_popup'); 

}
add_shortcode('gf_popup', 'gfpu_shortcode');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your default 'false' actually being parsed as false? If that's the case and its registering the default as a boolean could be expecting a string but getting a boolean? Long shot, as I think variables hold both interchangeably.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError` is a JavaScript error. Is there any JavaScript associated with this shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the defaults for `location` and `popTrigger` they have single quotes around them...

Assuming this is correct you need to add these around the new location value, so it does not think `bottom` is an (undefined) javascript variable, but rather a string value, via providing `'bottom'`...

Or if you don't want to modify code to add the single quotes, you could also just do: `[gf_popup pause="1000"  location="'bottom'"]` to pass the single quotes in via the shortcode attribute.